# How to enable the already disabled cell when user gets access how can I get back the same alternating row background

Tags: c#, wpf

I disabled the cell while typing the particular cell value is "AAA". I disabled by using `Enabled` property set to  false and also I changed the background to gray for the particular row .

```
void Grid_CurrentCellChanging(object sender,Syncfusion.Windows.ComponentModel.
      SyncfusionCancelRoutedEventArgs args)
{
        var Table = (sender as GridDataTableModel);
        var rowIndex = Grid.Model.CurrencyManager.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        var columnIndex = Grid.Model.CurrencyManager.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

        if (Grid.Model.CurrencyManager.CurrentCell.Renderer.ControlText=="AA")
        {
            Grid.Model.RowStyles[rowIndex].Enabled = false;
            Grid.Model.RowStyles[rowIndex].Background = Brushes.DarkGray;
            var rowcount = Grid.Model.View.Records.Count;

            if (this.Grid.Model.CurrencyManager.CurrentCell.RowIndex > rowcount)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,             new               Action(() =>
                {
                    this.Grid.Model.CurrencyManager.CurrentCell.MoveUp();
                }));
            }

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle , new Action( () =>
            {
                this.Grid.Model.CurrencyManager.CurrentCell.MoveDown();
            } ));
        }
}
```

I want to restore the same background while clicking the same disabled row.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save original background color when your gird is initialized. And restore this color when user click the row.